# Programmatically add glob to bash command

Tags: bash, glob

Looking for a way for me to expand a glob if my parameters aren't met in a bash script, I'm not positive but I think it might need eval or something of the sort, but I can't remember off the top of my head.

Function

```
function search ()
{
  [ 'x' == "${2}x" ] && {
    what="*"
  } || {
    what="${2}"
  }

  grep -n -Iir "${1}" "${what}"
}
```

Expected result without arg2

```
grep -n -Iir 'something' *  ## ran as the normal command
```

Comment: A bit of kibitzing -- the `function` keyword is a bashism, making your code incompatible with POSIX sh while adding no value over the POSIX-standard function declaration syntax

Comment: ...simultaneously, `==` is not valid inside POSIX test, for which the standard string comparison operator is `=`. The `[ "x" = "x$foo" ]` idiom, btw, is outright antique and unnecessary with correct use of test (proper quoting, not using the deprecated `-a` and `-o` logic operators, etc).

Comment: BTW, the original code was having the same results as `grep -n -Iir 'something' '*'` would; quoting the glob prevents its expansion. Usually that's what you want -- if you *didn't* quote the expansion of `$what`, then your function couldn't search filenames with spaces.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for the wisdom on the function literal meaning, I was completely unaware =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep in mind that a `*` is expanded to a list of filenames by the shell before `grep` is started. Thus, you can expand those yourself:

```
search() {
  local tgt=$1; shift      # move first argument into local variable tgt
  (( "$#" )) || set -- *   # if no other arguments exist, replace the remaining argument
                           # ...list with filenames in the current directory.
  grep -n -Iir "$tgt" "$@" # pass full list of arguments through to grep
}
```

Comment: Wow, plus one and accepted, thanks for the amazing quick response

Comment: As an aside, there's no need to quote expansions in `(( ))` as I do here; that's something entirely done for the benefit of StackOverflow's syntax highlighting engine.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntactic problem: you want `$2` to be quoted, but not if it's `*`. As a result, you just want two commands:

```
search () {
    if [ -z "$2" ]; then
        grep -n -Iir "$1" *
    else
        grep -n -Iir "$1" "$2"
    fi
}
```

Comment: I *assume* that the OP actually wants any extra arguments they have to be passed through, rather than having `search foo bar baz` ignore the `baz`, or `search foo *.txt` ignore all but the first text file matching the glob. Yes, their original code would have that bug, but that doesn't necessarily make it the Right Thing.